# Linq query producing incorrect result

Tags: c#, json, linq

Consider the following `linq` query

```
var result = from a in 
                 from b in filledTable
                 join c in distinctList on b[0].SerialNumber equals c.Field("SERIAL NUMBER")
                 select new { b, c }
             group a by new { a.b[0].SerialNumber } into d
             select new
             {
               Id = d.Select(x => x.b[0].Id),
               SerialNumber = d.Select(x => x.b[0].SerialNumber),
               // This part is not producing the correct output.
               ImportTable = d.Select(w => w.c.Table
                                              .AsEnumerable()
                                              .GroupBy(y => y.Field("SERIAL NUMBER"))
                                              .Select(z => z.First())
                                              .CopyToData‌​Table())
             };
```

`filledTable` in my linq query is a `List<dynamic>` which is populated by what the values are returned from a `sproc` and `distinctList` is a `List<DataRow>` which I distinct the values coming from the `DataTable` as follows:

```
List<DataRow> distinctList = dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default).ToList();
```

My `Linq` query produces the following `JSON`

```
[
{
"FilledTableList":[
  [
    {
      "Id":[
        2
      ],
      "SerialNumber":[
        "1073410"
      ],
      "ImportTable":[
        [
          {
            "SERIAL NUMBER":"1073410",
            "PRODUCT TYPE":"Product A"
          },
          {
            "SERIAL NUMBER":"1073411",
            "PRODUCT TYPE":"Product B"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id":[
        -1
      ],
      "SerialNumber":[
        "1073411"
      ],
      "ImportTable":[
        [
          {
            "SERIAL NUMBER":"1073410",
            "PRODUCT TYPE":"Proeduct A"
          },
          {
            "SERIAL NUMBER":"1073411",
            "PRODUCT TYPE":"Product B"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
]
}]
```

But I would like the following `JSON` output

```
[
{
"FilledTableList":[
  [
    {
      "Id":[
        2
      ],
      "SerialNumber":[
        "1073410"
      ],
      "ImportTable":[
        [
          {
            "SERIAL NUMBER":"1073410",
            "PRODUCT TYPE":"Product A"
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id":[
        -1
      ],
      "SerialNumber":[
        "1073411"
      ],
      "ImporTable":[
        [
          {
            "SERIAL NUMBER":"1073411",
            "PRODUCT TYPE":"Product B"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
]
}]
```

So the `ImportTable` node only contains the information matching to the serial number in the above `FilleTabledList` node. Everything else seems to work as expected by the `Linq` query apart from this. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please

Update:

My `filledTable` contains two items as follows:

```
{ Id = 2, SerialNumber = "1073410"}
{ Id = -1, SerialNumber = "1073411"}
```

Eventually I will have more items in the list but just to figure out why more linq query isn't working I have narrowed it down to just to items

Comment: So you want return  public List<List<>> FilledTableList { get; set; }? This what you try to return . Your JSON is still incorrect.

Comment: @mww Yes if its even possible

Comment: It's really hard to reproduce your problem, due to the fact that you didn't provide any source data. Can you fill in some source data for filledTable (4 - 10 elements) from which you like to produce that output (I think distinctList contains just one element with serial 1073411)?

Comment: @Oliver The initial values in my `DataTable` consist of 4 serials which I've manually made up of **1073410*, **1073410**, **1073411**, **1073410** so when I do `dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default).ToList();` to get the distinct values then I get two elements which consist of **1073410** and **1073411**

Comment: @Oliver I've also updated my question

Comment: Is it a typo in the serial? `{ Id = -1, SerialNumber = "1073410"}` Otherwise I don't really understand what you expect from `1073411`

Comment: @grek40 my apologies, that was a typo

Comment: Can you clarify whether there is any case where `distinctList` contains two entries with the same serial? If not: as far as I see, `ImportTable` would always contain a table with exactly one row (and this row needs to be with the correct serial), right?

Comment: @grek40 The `distinctList` can never contain more than one serial number and correct for the second point

Answer (score 3):

I [created a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LYiY1S), which makes it easier to communicate the available data and the expected results.

When I understood it correctly you like to get a list of all products, listed in the filledTable and then find all elements with the same serial number from the dataTable.

If this is correct, than the LINQ query has to be:

```
    var result = filledTable.GroupJoin(distinctList, product => product.SerialNumber, row => row.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER"), (Product, Rows) => new { Product, Rows })
                            .Select(group => new
                                    {
                                        Id = group.Product.Id,
                                        SerialNumber = group.Product.SerialNumber,
                                        ImportTable = group.Rows.CopyToDataTable()
                                    });
```

and the result will be

```
[
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "SerialNumber": "1073410",
    "ImportTable": [
      {
        "SERIAL NUMBER": "1073410",
        "PRODUCT TYPE": "Product A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": -1,
    "SerialNumber": "1073411",
    "ImportTable": [
      {
        "SERIAL NUMBER": "1073411",
        "PRODUCT TYPE": "Product B"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Actually, as far as I understand, there will be at most one row in `distinctList` for each specific serial number. So there should be no need for the `ImportTable` in its current form if you try to compress the json.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will have a go at this. Just a quick one, if I was to move the items from `ImporTable` and have them all as one item. i.e. all items from `filledTable` and `distinctList` how would I go about that for the query?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your request. Can you provide some sample input data and the desired output?

Comment: Sorry, if I wanted my `json` to look like **[this](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/Actions#act-listAction)** websites but containing all my information from both `filledTable` and `distinctList` as one `List<T>` or another appropriate collection type

Comment: Don't exactly understand, where the problem is, but if you simply want to export a single element as an list of elements you could e.g. write `Id = new[] { group.Product.Id }`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure, but would something like this work?

```
       var result = (from a in (from b in filledTable join c in distinctList on b[0].SerialNumber equals c.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER") select new { b, c })
                      group a by new { a.b[0].SerialNumber } into d
                      select new
                      {
                          Id = d.Select(x => x.b[0].Id),
                          SerialNumber = d.Select(x => x.b[0].SerialNumber),
                          ImportTable = d.Select(w => w.c.Table.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(y=>y.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER") == d.Key.ToString())
                          .GroupBy(y => y.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER")).Select(z => z.First()).CopyToData‌​Table())
                      });
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have `d.Key.SerialNumber` in the added `Where` clause? Also, I think this answer is kindof the minimal change set to get the expected results, but it doesn't address any of the underlying design issues (overly complicated query for simple result).

Comment: @grek40 that is true, though provided quite a weird input and output data (for instance, most of the arrays in results are probably not supposed to be arrays) I presume fixing the design issues are outside of the scope of the answer. Although query simplification could do some help indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified query that can be used:

```
var result =
    from entry in filledTable
    join row in distinctList on entry[0].SerialNumber equals row.Field<string>("SERIAL NUMBER")
    group new { entry, row } by entry[0].SerialNumber into items
    select new
    {
        Id = items.Select(x => x.entry[0].Id),
        SerialNumber = new[] { items.Key }.AsEnumerable(),
        ImportTable = items.Select(x => x.row).CopyToDataTable()
    };
```

It should be equivalent to the desired output and deal with most strange data combinations that are handled by the original query.

Comment: I think I'm making my query way too complex like you mention. After reading your comments on @bashis answer I need to re-think this part. I'll have a go at your answer and see how I get on. Eventually I want my final `json` object to look like as it is on **[this](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/Actions#act-listAction)** website. So if I could somehow get a List<T> or something which contains all the information from my `filedTable` and `distinctList` as one full item

Comment: You should definitely first define the desired result data set (for each entry, which information is needed, no duplicates within one entry!), then think of its structure (json or whatever, nested vs flat) and define the query to transform your input into the target structure.